# How to create pipe in Angular?

Tags: angular

In Angular, how can I create pipe and apply sort.

I don't know how to create. Can any one give me any guidance on this?

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data | keyvalue">
     <div *ngFor='let obj of item.value;  index as i'>
                 {{ obj.curdate }}
         {{ obj.time }}
     </div>
 </div>
```

I saw a lot of answers on this subject.

But I don't know where to create this file and how to call in my component.

Can suggest step by step tutorial on this.

I tried this,

pipe/orderBy.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "sort"
})
export class ArraySortPipe  implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: any, field: string): any[] {
    if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
      return;
    }
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a[field] < b[field]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[field] > b[field]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }
}
```

in app.module.ts

```
import { ArraySortPipe } from './pipe/orderBy.pipe';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ArraySortPipe
    ],
```

mycomponent.ts

```
import { ArraySortPipe } from '../../../pipe/orderBy.pipe';
```

mytemplate

```
<th *ngFor="let obj of item.value;  index as i | sort: 'obj.curdate'">{{obj.curdate}}</th>
```

I followed above method but i got an error.

**compiler.js:2547 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("
        
            
            ]*ngFor="let obj of item.value;  index as i | sort: 'obj.curdate'">{{obj.curdate}}**

Comment: To me it is a bit unclear what you want. Also can you show us what you have tried or what you have tried searching for?

Comment: well i am not start yet because i don't know where to create pip function under which folder and how to call on this

Comment: Are you referring to [pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes)?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes It's well documented, try something first ;)

Comment: @ChrisW. can you please check my updated question

Comment: The code you provided doesn't seem to be the problem. The actual problem appears to be that somewhere you call `toUpperCase` on an undefined string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code tries to apply the pipe to the "i" variable, which in fact is the index of the array.

Try out this way

```
<th *ngFor="let obj of item.value | sort: 'obj.curdate';  index as i ">{{obj.curdate}}</th>
```

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you mean a **pipe**.

[This tutorial](https://toddmotto.com/angular-pipes-custom-pipes) is pretty good imho, it should help you.

Some extracts:

**Create your pipe:**

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'filesize' })
export class FileSizePipe {}
```

**Declare it on your NgModules**

```
import { FileSizePipe } from './filesize.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    //...
    FileSizePipe,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**Implement PipeTransform**

```
export class FileSizePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(size: number): string {
    return (size / (1024 * 1024)).toFixed(2) + 'MB';
  }
}
```

**And then just use it**

```
<p>{{ file.size | filesize }}</p>
```

The tutorial has a lot more of details, and I can help you if you have some doubts too.

**EDIT:** Also you can see [the official guide](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes), that has a lot of details.

Comment: You don't call "toUpperCase()" anywhere in that code, so the problem is most likely somewhere else